# Testing in Maven Project: Can't find code to test

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit

When I'm working in a simple command line java application in IntelliJ, I can store the tests in the same folder as the rest of my code and just run JUnit tests with the built in tools. It may not be best practice to put my tests in the same folder as my other code, but I'm just using the tests to study Java.

Today, I created an empty Maven project (I didn't use an archetype.) and the structure seems to want me to put tests in a special test/java folder. According to a comment on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589102/point-of-maven-test-directory), "the code in src/test can see src/main, but code in src/main can't use/see/compile against code in src/test," but I haven't found this to be the case. My IDE has red squiggly lines under references to the classes in my main/java file, and says, "Cannot resolve symbol 'User'." I'm wondering if I might be missing something from my test file:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class UserTest {

    private User benny;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        benny = new User("benny", "long", 46, 'M');
    }

    @Test
    public void getFirstNameReturnsName() {
        assertEquals("We should receive the correct name", "benny", benny.getFirstName());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As does happen, while I was writing my question I found the solution. Blurg!

```
import gabrielkunkel.User; // <-- I had to import the class
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class UserTest {

    private User benny;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        benny = new User("benny", "long", 46, 'M');
    }


    @Test
    public void getFirstNameReturnsName() {
        assertEquals("We should receive the correct name", "benny", benny.getFirstName());
    }
}
```

In my former set-up this wasn't necessary. I will definitely give credit to someone that can give some better advice or alternative methods. :-)

Comment: You always need to import the classes that are outside the package you're working if want to use the short class name. [More info here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html).

Comment: Ah! Yes, before I was including it in the same package. It seems like IntelliJ wiped the package name off the test file's first line when I copied it over from my other project and I didn't realize that I don't want my test files a part of my *package.*

Comment: If you like your answer you can accept it. SO will then show the question as answered.

Comment: Thanks @DavidNewcomb I have to wait 2 days. :-)

Comment: Most developers put tests in the same package as the class under test. This avoids the import statement and has some other benefits, too (e.g. accessing package private fields and methods)

Comment: @StefanBirkner Swell! I prefer that, but will Maven be smart enough to skip test files on *compile* or does it need some further configuration when test files are mingling with production files like Webpack does?

Comment: You have the same packages/directories in `src/test/java` like in `src/main/java` and Maven separates tests from production code. You may have a look at some Maven projects on GitHub. E.g. https://github.com/stefanbirkner/system-rules